# How do you solve quadratic inequalities/functions?

Tags: inequality, quadratics, functional-inequalities

> Find the least value of $n$ such that $(n-2)x^2+8x+n+4 > 0$, where $x  \in \mathbb R$  and  $n \in \mathbb N$.

**What I did -**

As $x$ is real, $D>0$

$64-4(n+4)(n-2)>0$

$(n-4)(n-6)<0$

$n \epsilon (-6,4)$

But as $n \epsilon N$

The least value is 3

**According to the book's method,**

$n-2>0$

$n>2$

And,

$64-4(n-2)(n+4)<0$

$(n-4)(n+6)>0$

$n>4$

And least value of n comes out to be 5.

I don't understand why D<0 when x is real?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the case $n=0$ gives $$x^2-4x-2<0$$ which is not fulfilled for all real $x$
$$n=1$$ gives $$x^2-8x-5<0$$
$$n=2$$ gives $$8x+6>0$$
for $$n>2$$ we get
$$x^2+2\left(\frac{4}{n-2}\right)x+\left(\frac{4}{n-2}\right)^2+\frac{n+4}{n-2}-\left(\frac{4}{n-2}\right)^2>0$$ and we get
$$\left(x+\frac{4}{n-2}\right)^2+\frac{n^2+2n-24}{(n-2)^2}>0$$
finally we get the answer $$n=5$$ then we have
$$\left(x+\frac{4}{3}\right)^2+\frac{11}{9}>0$$

Comment: If $n=4$ and $x=-2$ it is zero.

Comment: How did you manipulate the equation to that form? (When n>2)

Comment: but i have wrote each step for you! Complete square is my hint

Comment: Got it. I haven't slept in 2 nights. Please pardon me.

Comment: no problem, it is nice that a could help you

Answer (score 0):

Let's define $D=64−4(n+4)(n−2)$ and $f(x)=(n−2)x^2+8x+n+4$.
If $D>0$ then $f(x)$ vanishes for two values of $x$. But we don't want $f(x)=0$, we need instead $f(x)>0$ for every $x$. That can happen only if $D<0$.